# Subscribe Box style is being over rode somewhere, can't figure how where

Tags: css

I am trying to style my subscription box on http://wpdallas.com/test/ like the one on http://noahsdad.com If you notice the subscribe box is much smaller. I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I'm assuming there is a style that I need to override, but can't figure out what it is.

Thanks.

Comment: I can see the code, but I can't see why the subscribe box is smaller in the one theme, vs the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the button's padding.  You defined it in your style.css, when you set it for all `input[type="submit"]`s.  Try just lowering those numbers.